# Springboot Joint table from different database

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I have a Springboot project with two datasource configured one for each database I'm using. Everything works, but I need to create an Entity in database one that refers to an entity from database 2. The problem is that the entity in the second database is not found.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "data", catalog = "data")
public class Data implements Serializable
{
   //all stuff related to data here.
   @ManyToOne
   private User user;
   //Entity User is store in the second database
}
```

Is there anyway to tell spring that the entity User can be found in the second datasource?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't mix datasources

Comment: That is what I thought. I do not close the post, since I wait for a link to something official